# PHP get JSON details

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file (show bellow) that contains weather information that I am extracting with php unfrotunately I am stuck as I failed to get weather description:

```
  object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
  ["city_id"]=> int(2650225)
  ["main"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
        ["temp"]=> float(286.96)
        ["temp_min"]=> float(286.15)
        ["temp_max"]=> float(289.82)
        ["pressure"]=> int(1001)
        ["humidity"]=> int(66)
  }
  ["wind"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
        ["speed"]=> int(7)
        ["deg"]=> int(230)
  }
  ["clouds"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["all"]=> int(40)
  }
  ["weather"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
            ["id"]=> int(802)
            ["main"]=> string(6) "Clouds"
            ["description"]=> string(16) "scattered clouds"
            ["icon"]=> string(3) "03d"
        }
  }
  ["dt"]=> int(1349096400)
  ["dt_iso"]=> string(29) "2012-10-01 13:00:00 +0000 UTC"
}
```

While I am able to get all other details like city and temperature, wind speed, etc 
I am unable to get weather->main or weather-description

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've done to get some of the other details:

```
<?php
$strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$array = json_decode($strJsonFileContents);
$value = array_values($array)[0];

$city = $value->city_id;
$temp = (($value->main->temp) - 273.15);
$humidity = $value->main->humidity;
// FAILS
$cast = $value->weather->main;
$weather = $value->weather->description;
?>
```

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: @R10t-- It appears to be already parsed and the resulting PHP object was dumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `wheater` is an array. That's why you are failing to access `main` and `description` directly. Try this:

```
$cast = $value->weather[0]->main;
$weather = $value->weather[0]->description;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly I am sure I tried that before and there was an error but happy it worked.